# Drawing to render buffer without using renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, opengl-es, macos

I have edited my question, I found a question/answer that seems to be along the same line as mine ([Draw to offscreen renderbuffer in OpenGL ES (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853551/draw-to-offscreen-renderbuffer-in-opengl-es-iphone)). I want to not use presentRenderBuffer: and renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable: and the drawing to texture seems to be the best option.

The reason I need to do this, is the app is being ported from iOS to Mac and I have used the Chameleon Project to do some of this - so I cannot us a NSOpenGLView, but I also cannot use an EAGLContext since that was not ported via the project.

I have tried to follow the advice by Quakeboy but I could not get it to work, I was trying it on the default Xcode4 iOS OpenGL-ES project. If anyone could provide me with help on how to convert the default project over by using his method I should be able to figure it out for my app.

Comment: The only way I know of on iOS is to use those methods. Each platform provides some of it's own OpenGL facilities and each requires your own code. If you need it to work on Mac as well, abstract the buffer creation code and write it differently for each platform.